# Remove admin registration route from rails-api devise_token_auth project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to prevent rails from exposing the devise_token_auth registration route so that admins can only be created from the console.

My admin.rb looks like this:

```
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :confirmable,
         :recoverable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :omniauthable

  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User
end
```

I'm not sure what I should put in my config/routes.rb to prevent rails from exposing the route.

Comment: removing :registerable ,:omniauthable  and :confirmable will do the trick.
This way you won't have any way to reg an admin thrugh the app and the routes will not be used. Try it.

Comment: When I remove these I am still able to reg an admin; do I need to change something somewhere else to make this kick in?  Also, since this frequently causes a problem although may not be one here, I am using rails-api.

Comment: I think I found a way to solve it. Haven't tested it, but it makes sense.

Comment: Does mount_devise_token_auth for 'Admin', :skip => [:registrations]  even work with devise_token_auth?

Comment: So, that's the issue I've been circling around; I didn't realize that it only removes the controller, as opposed to the route itself.  So when you send a request to that route, instead of saying it doesn't exist, it gives an error related to the controller.  This effectively blocks admin registration, but you do have to attempt a registration to see that it has taken effect (the paths will still be there.)  But this works.  A little strange, but functional, and in the docs. https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth#using-multiple-models (look for "excluding modules", down slightly)

Comment: The problem with this gem is that it lacks a huge chunk of what devise offers in terms of functionality. Being able to remove some of the default routes is something they should look into.  I'll add my answer back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `:registerable ,:omniauthable and :confirmable`  from the model should do the trick.

Try adding this to your routes as well:

```
 mount_devise_token_auth for 'Admin', at: 'admin_auth', :skip => [:registrations]
```

Comment: Not sure if it is important, but the syntax I used is slightly different: mount_devise_token_auth for 'Admin', at: 'admin_auth', skip: [:registrations] (with 'admin_auth' being whatever you declared in the generator)  The part of note being skip: instead of :skip =>

Comment: Can you paste it over?

Comment: Sorry, hit enter to add a new line and it posted before I entered the format. :)